"migrant worker population" or "migrant workers population"
I'm always confused when it comes to whether to use plural or singular attributive nouns. I know the general rule, which is to use the singular form in cases where you are unsure, but every once in a while, I encounter the opposite. So, what about this case?

The UK's migrant [worker or workers] population increases considerably every year.


Personally, I would reposition population. You already have two noun adjuncts UK and migrant that modify workers. The addition of  UK qualifies which group of migrant workers we are referring to.

The population of UK migrant workers steadily increases every year

We can say a population belongs to a country or state:

The UK's population of migrant workers …

This can be reworded as:

The population of migrant workers in the UK increases steadily…

Use the plural form, workers, to clarify that you are talking about a group of people.
If you had to write the title of a research paper or report, the singular  worker would be acceptable. Personally, I find four nouns in a row to be overkill but it is not unusual.

The UK Migrant Worker Population

For example; The Unsigned United Nations Migrant Worker Rights Convention:

Really helpful answer! Thank you!

@anIELTSlearner my pleasure!

By the way, in your opinion, how many attributive words preceding a noun start to be too many and need rephrasing?

There is no limit, and the number of attributive nouns (adjuncts) is a matter of style. The more adjuncts are added the less clearer its meaning becomes.
